# Using make_template() in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use make_template() to avoid passing reuse flag throughout my model. But it seems that make_template() doesn't work correctly when it is used inside of a python class. I pasted ]my model code and the error I am getting below. It is a simple MLP to train on the MNIST dataset.

Since the code is kinda long, the main part here is the _weights() function. I try to wrap it using make_template() and then use get_variables() inside it to create and reuse weights throughout my model. _weights() is used by _create_dense_layer() and that in turn is used by _create_model() to create the graph. The train() function accepts tensors that I get from a data reader.

Model

```
class MLP(object):
    def __init__(self, hidden=[], biases=False, activation=tf.nn.relu):
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        self.hidden = hidden
        self.activation = activation
        self.biases = biases
        self.n_features = 784
        self.n_classes = 10
        self.bsize = 100
        self.l2 = 0.1

    def _real_weights(self, shape):
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
        weights = tf.get_variable('weights', shape, initializer=initializer)
        return weights
    # use make_template to make variable reuse transparent
    _weights = tf.make_template('_weights', _real_weights)

    def _real_biases(self, shape):
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)
        return tf.get_variable('biases', shape, initializer=initializer)
    # use make_template to make variable reuse transparent
    _biases = tf.make_template('_biases', _real_biases)

    def _create_dense_layer(self, name, inputs, n_in, n_out, activation=True):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            weights = self._weights([n_in, n_out])
            layer = tf.matmul(inputs, weights)
            if self.biases:
                biases = self._biases([n_out])
                layer = layer + biases
            if activation:
                layer = self.activation(layer)
            return layer

    def _create_model(self, inputs):
        n_in = self.n_features
        for i in range(len(self.hidden)):
            n_out = self.hidden[i]
            name = 'hidden%d' % (i)
            inputs = self._create_dense_layer(name, inputs, n_in, n_out)
            n_in = n_out
        output = self._create_dense_layer('output', inputs, n_in, self.n_classes, activation=False)    
        return output

    def _create_loss_op(self, logits, labels):
        cent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
        weights = self.graph.get_collection('weights')
        l2 = (self.l2 / self.bsize) * tf.reduce_sum([tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w)) for w in weights])
        return tf.reduce_mean(cent, name='loss') + l2

    def _create_train_op(self, loss):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        return optimizer.minimize(loss)

    def _create_accuracy_op(self, logits, labels):
        predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
        errors = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(errors, tf.float32))

    def train(self, images, labels):
        logits = model._create_model(images)
        loss = model._create_loss_op(logits, labels)
        return model._create_train_op(loss)       

    def accuracy(self, images, labels):
        logits = model._create_model(images)
        return model._create_accuracy_op(logits, labels)

    def predict(self, images):
        return model._create_model(images)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     25     model = MLP(hidden=[128])
     26     # define ops
---> 27     train = model.train(images, labels)
     28     accuracy = model.accuracy(eval_images, eval_labels)
     29     # load test data and create a prediction op

 in train(self, images, labels)
     60 
     61     def train(self, images, labels):
---> 62         logits = model._create_model(images)
     63         loss = model._create_loss_op(logits, labels)
     64         return model._create_train_op(loss)

 in _create_model(self, inputs)
     39             n_out = self.hidden[i]
     40             name = 'hidden%d' % (i)
---> 41             inputs = self._create_dense_layer(name, inputs, n_in, n_out)
     42             n_in = n_out
     43         output = self._create_dense_layer('output', inputs, n_in, self.n_classes, activation=False)

 in _create_dense_layer(self, name, inputs, n_in, n_out, activation)
     25     def _create_dense_layer(self, name, inputs, n_in, n_out, activation=True):
     26         with tf.variable_scope(name):
---> 27             weights = self._weights([n_in, n_out])
     28             layer = tf.matmul(inputs, weights)
     29             if self.biases:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/template.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    265           self._unique_name, self._name) as vs:
    266         self._var_scope = vs
--> 267         return self._call_func(args, kwargs, check_for_new_variables=False)
    268 
    269   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/template.py in _call_func(self, args, kwargs, check_for_new_variables)
    206           ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES))
    207 
--> 208       result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
    209       if check_for_new_variables:
    210         trainable_variables = ops.get_collection(

TypeError: _real_weights() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shape'

originally defined at:
  File "", line 1, in 
    class MLP(object):
  File "", line 17, in MLP
    _weights = tf.make_template('_weights', _real_weights)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code as it is here, e.g. the `model` references in the `train`, `accuracy` and `predict` methods. I assume this is due to cutting the code from its natural habitat.

The reason for the `TypeError` you mention,

```py
TypeError: _real_weights() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shape'
```

most likely comes from the fact that `_real_weights` itself is an instance method of the `MLP` class, not a regular function or static method. As such, the first parameter to the function is always the `self` reference pointing to the instance of the class at the time of the call (an explicit version of the `this` pointer in C-like languages), as can be seen in the function declaration:

```py
def _real_weights(self, shape):
    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights', shape, initializer=initializer)
    return weights
```

Note that even though you don't use the argument, it's still required in this case. Thus when creating a template of the function using

```py
tf.make_template('_weights', self._real_weights)
```

you basically state that the `_weights` template you create should take two positional arguments: `self` and `weights` (as does the `_real_weights` method). Consequently, when you call the function created from the template as

```py
weights = self._weights([n_in, n_out])
```

you pass the array to the `self` argument, leaving the (required) `shape` argument unspecified.

From what it looks like you'd have two options here: You could either make `_real_weights` a regular function outside of the `MLP` class, so that

```py
def _real_weights(shape):
    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights', shape, initializer=initializer)
    return weights

class MLP():
    # etc.
```

which is probably not what you want, given that you already created a class for the model - or you could explicitly make it a static method of the `MLP` class, so that

```py
class MLP():
    @staticmethod
    def _real_weights(shape):
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
        weights = tf.get_variable('weights', shape, initializer=initializer)
        return weights
```

Since static methods by definition do not operate on a class instance, you can (and have to) omit the `self` reference.

You would then create the templates as

```py
tf.make_template('_weights', _real_weights)
```

in the first case and

```py
tf.make_template('_weights', MLP._real_weights)
```

in the second case, explicitly specifying the class `MLP` as the name scope of the static method. Either way, the `_real_weights` function/method and the `_weights` template both now have only one argument, the shape of the variable to create.

Comment: "you pass the array to the self argument"

Why? I am calling it as a method `self._weights([in, out])`, so the first argument of self should be included automatically by python

Comment: Because `_weights` is a free function created by `tf.make_template`, not a class method. The reference to the original class is lost, so Python does not know about `self`.

Comment: But the function generated by make_template is assigned to a class member, so it is actually a method and it is being called like one

Comment: Well, try it. :) https://gist.github.com/sunsided/3e603f4cf3265fbb61c9da56a265259d

Comment: But this is not what happens in my code. If I change your example to what actually happens in MLP() it works :)
https://gist.github.com/MadWombat/dfb667614ff9c8b2a55e32f6aa1ab46f

Comment: Ah, my bad. The indentation caught me off guard. So .. does the rest still solve your problem then?

Comment: Well, it has been a while, I have rewritten my model code from scratch since then anyway. Switching to static methods should work, since weight initialization doesn't really need access to self. In my current model code, I just initialize all the weights in __init__.py and use the reuse flag in scope later.

Comment: I am still somewhat puzzled by this. Seems almost like make_template doesn't see the first argument if the function is called as a method. I wonder why.